# custom b2b app also in regular store

Tags: ios, itunes, appstore-approval, b2b

I was wondering if it would be possible to submit the same app in the regular iTunes Store as in the Custom B2B Store? We've got an app we would like the general public to pay for but give it for free to people who purchased another product of ours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is NO.  Once an app is Custom B2B, it's always Custom B2B.

BUT:

You can create a new app with a slightly different name and submit that app to the AppStore.  For example:

```
 Custom B2B App Name: com.yourcompany.AppName
 New App in AppStore: com.yourcompany.App-Name
```

I'm not sure how different the names need to be but you can experiment until you find a name the AppStore will take.